# Arduino Endless Loop of Array

Tags: loops, arduino

I need help to create endless loop for items in array, I want loop restart automaticly ;

My code is below ;

```
const int myArray [] = {3,5,6,7,1,2};
 
void loop() {
    for (int element : myArray) {
              Serial.println(element);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `loop()` function itself is already an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in an infinite loop

```
while (true) {
    for (int element : myArray) {
       Serial.println(element);
    }
}
```

As pointed out by hcheung in their comments, your `loop()` function should already be called as part of an infinite loop. Since that does not seem to be the case, then it is highly likely you have an error somewhere in your code. Have a look at the link posted by hcheung, which is a very basic Arduino application, and make sure you have something similar on your end, at least as far as the endless `for` loop calling `loop()` goes.

Comment: The question is about `Arduino`, and in Arduino, the `loop()` is already an infinite `for(;;)` loop, see [the source code](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp#L45-L48)

Comment: @hcheung You have a point. However, OP's setup is clearly different in some significant way.